# Anyone else going to NECSS 2015?

Tags: discussion, conference

Registration just opened for the [North East Conference on Science and Skepticism](http://necss.org/). I have already put in my registration, so as to make sure that I go!  I will be going to workshops as well as the main conference (and Drinking Skeptically).  I am going to try to get an opportunity to make a presentation if Susan Gerbic can't make it.

Anyway, hotels are expensive (even with the discount), so if anyone is going, let's at least coordinate.

**UPDATE**: I am talking to one of the co-chairs of the NECSS Organizing Committee. If they can't get Susan Gerbic to come, I may actually be on a panel at the conference. I plan to make sure to bring up Skeptics StackExchange if I am on that panel!

Comment: A little far for me Steve.  Will StackExchange sponsor you?

Comment: Jason, I'll ask as it get's closer. If I am on a panel, I am not sure what sort of considerations NECSS would give in terms of conference fees.